# Django Particular wise total in their respective rows

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to print a particular wise total in the invoice using Django. The problem is if I use for loop, it prints the last items particular wise total in everywhere. I am confused what will be the best way to calculate individual total in their respective rows?
Here is my Views.py:

def order_complete(request):

```
order_number = request.GET.get('order_number')
transID = request.GET.get('payment_id')

try:
    order = Order.objects.get(order_number=order_number, is_ordered=True)
    ordered_products = OrderProduct.objects.filter(order_id = order.id)
    total=0
    subtotal = 0
    for i in ordered_products:
        total = i.product_price * i.quantity
        subtotal += total
    payment = Payment.objects.get(payment_id = transID)
    context ={
        'order': order,
        'ordered_products': ordered_products,
        'order_number': order.order_number,
        'transID': payment.payment_id,
        'payment': payment,
        'subtotal': subtotal,
        'total':total,

    }
    return render(request, 'orders/order_complete.html', context)
except(Payment.DoesNotExist, Order.DoesNotExist):
    return redirect('home')
```

models.py

class OrderProduct(models.Model):

```
order           =   models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
payment         =   models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
user            =   models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
product         =   models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
variations      = models.ManyToManyField(Variation, blank=True)
quantity        =   models.IntegerField()
product_price   =   models.FloatField()
ordered         =   models.BooleanField(default=False)
created_at      =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at      =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.product.product_name
```

template

```
          <dd class="text-right">${{ total }}</dd>
```

suggestion/solutions would be highly appreciated.
Here is the result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to always store `total_amount` in the table itself along with `unit_price` and `quantity`,

Cause this way, if you ever want to get the item's unit cost you can simply access it on order table itself and total to tell that this is the `total` of `unit price x quantity`

1 more advantage you get by this i.e. when calculating the final total of all order items you can simply write the following to get it

```
from django.db.models import Sum

order_products = OrderProduct.objects.filter(order_id=order.id)
total_amount = order_products.aggregate(Sum('total_amount'))["total_amount__sum"]
# total_amount is the new field to add in OrderProduct table which stores
# quantity * unit_price at the time of creation
```

This way, you will directly get individual total & sum of those totals

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. your suggestion is really helpful to solve the issue.